# How to see all output in Far 3?

Tags: windows, far-manager

I want to see all output even if it is huge.
For example, running `systeminfo` via regular command line prompt in Windows will show everything with vertical scrolling.
But when I'm invoking the same command in Far 3 I'm able to see just the end of information that fit in one screen.

Comment: One other option is to pipe you command output into standard windows MORE command like so : 
c:\>systeminfo|MORE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I realise this is old, and you've already accepted your answer, but I believe that Far 3 comes with the `FarCmds` plugin (certainly the nightly build that I just downloaded does).

This allows you to copy the output of commands into the edit or view windows, using the `edit:`, `view:` and other "commands"... like so:

```
C:\tmp> edit:< systeminfo
```

Basically, it's redirecting the command `systeminfo` into an instance of the editor.  You can even copy directly to the clipboard by using `clip:` instead.  `FarCmds` is one of my most-used plugins.

Comment: Indeed, very good solution! `FarCmds` is also bundled in the last 1.75 release of FAR.

Answer (score 2):

Problem can be solved by configuring properties of Far window.
Increasing a value of *right click at title bar -> Properties -> Layout -> Screen buffer size -> Height* leads to a proper result.

Answer (score 2):

If you run Farmanager from [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) you could run the command and append `-new_console:c` to it to put it in a new console with the press any key to continue output. You will be able to scroll up.